# IE8 changes href after pasteHtml

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I have to follwing problem while inserting link (a) elements in a designMode activated iframe in IE8:

Lets say i have this string:

```
<a href="test" target="_self">totest</a>
```

When inserted with pasteHtml(), IE8 turns this into:

```
<A href="http://servername/pathToScript/test" target=_self>totest</A>
```

I do not want the server path in there just the href i supplied (test)
I guess i could use the replace() method to remove the server path but is there a more general solution to somehow turn this off or something?

Comment: There is a `nameProp` property in IE, maybe you can use that. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534180%28v=vs.85%29.aspx